# BootStrap glyphicon-calender icon separated from input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am new to bootStrap and Html. I am currently using the Bootstrap 3 Datepicker and I have a problem. The glyphicon-calendar icon is separated away from the input textbox. How do I fix this? Here is the screenshot of my problem and my codes. In addition, if you manage to solve my problem, can you provide an explanation on how you solve it? I would like to learn more.

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmTge.png)

```js
$(function () {
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker();
    });
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is proper code just add this bootstrap js and css see the output

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```